# Create and update item from one list to another in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, csom

Using Javascript in SharePoint, I need to create a list item in listA in a siteA, then create an identical list item in a listB in siteB.
Both lists would use same content type (with the same number of columns).

If an item is created in listA for the first time, then listB would create the same item and after that only update the same item using an ID column.

This is the code I have written so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(updateListItem, "sp.js");

function updateListItem() {  
    var siteURL = "https://phessp.webhc.hctx.net/pmo/projectsitetemplate";
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext(siteURL);
    var oList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Project Information');

    //ProjectID is the field in current list, I am using this ID to locate the same record with same ProjecdID for update

    var itemId = toString(GetUrlKeyValue('ProjectID'));  
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(itemId);
    oListItem.set_item('Timeline_x0020_Description', 'My Updated Timeline');
    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {
    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}

</script>
```

I tried multiple approaches but am having issues.

Comment: What version of SharePoint are you using? And are the sites in the same site collection?

Comment: I am using SP 2013 On Premise. Yes, they are in the same site collection using the same content type.

Comment: This is the code I have written so far, I am new to this code so please excuse my low level skills :

Comment: Will the item in ListA only ever be updated through the JavaScript, or do you need to also worry about sync'ing changes made when users update the list item directly?

Comment: So think of ListA as a master list, any change to listA need to be reflected in listB, and I need to do using ItemEditForm of list in sharepoint.
Both lists are in different sites. ListB should take values from ListA fields without hard coded, only dynamic.

Do you think you can suggest a solution, thanks.